# React Native - Is it ok if I hide warning in react native?

Tags: react-native, warnings

I am new to react native and I am having a warning that I just don't know how to get rid of it, is it ok if I just hide it as long as it does not become an error to crush my app?

The warning I receive:

Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods
should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects
are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

I tried to manage to not happen this warning but if I register a user and than go back to signupscreen and if I try to register another one the warning comes up.

Answer (score 0):

To help with this problem I need to have your code from render() function. You can Upload it here. Then I can review your code. It will help to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi Denis, I updated the post and you can find mu code there, please help me if you can. Thanks

Comment: first of all, your render function should return null, if !error. It's a good practice.
seconds - remove shouldComponentUpdate and you will see your problem. I'm thinking that your react component has a performance problem and without shouldComponentUpdate your will see it. It's should be fixed first.

Comment: Also you can remove your code blocks on each other from render function and it's a good way to find an error

Comment: yes I know about the shouldComponentUpdate, it is my solution so my app doesn't crach. How can I manage so I can change my props how I want and not get this warning ?

Comment: sorry mate, ask @hash about your problem. He has a god mode here and maybe knows better about your problem than me.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to resolve that warning, you need to look where your updates to the state are happening.

If you do updates to the state or props inside of your render function you are creating infinite render loops.